# Error adding scaffolded controller in asp.net core 1.1 using VS2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm using VS2017 on a brand new ASP.net core web application (version 1.1) and when I try to add 'api controller with actions using entity framework' I get the following error message:

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Version for
>   package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools' could not be
>   resolved.'

I've googled a bit and found a few suggestions, one of which was to add a CLI tool reference in the .csproj file, so I have added the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" 
         Version="1.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This version matched the installed version according to the NuGet package manager. However the problem still persists. Any suggestions on how to fix this please?

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours of headbanging, I stumbled across this post: [System could not be found Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Core project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742586/system-could-not-be-found-visual-studio-2017-asp-net-core-project)

I followed the advice to enable automatic check for missing packages and it finally worked!

> I had the same problem, first when converting a VS2015 net core mvc web project to 2017 and then when trying to create a new core web application in 2017.
>
> Went to Tools|NuGet Package Manager|Package Manager Settings - checked 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages' and 'Automatically check for missing packages during build in VS' and then clicked 'Clear All NuGet Cache(s)'.
>   Then re-built the solution - it found and loaded all the required packages and ran OK.
>
> May not work for all cases but simple and worth a try.