# How to add "System" as reference in my file csproj

Tags: c#

I have this error:

> The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

And my `.csproj` file contains:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I created the project with the command "dotnet new console"

Would like to know if it is possible, how to generate this (not manually) but with the help of "dotnet"

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742586/system-could-not-be-found-visual-studio-2017-asp-net-core-project

Comment: I don't use visual studio

Comment: If not manually, than what is the tool?

Comment: Notepad++ with Dotnet

Comment: Can you show us the .cs file that the error refers to? It might be missing a ```using``` statement.